# Why does bash 4.3 keep allocating memory in a script

Tags: bash, dash, memory-leaks

Why does this shell script gradually consume more memory in bash? I’m not using any local variables. Although the value of `cpid` is changing at every iteration because `ls` exits immediately, it should never grow too large.

The shell script in question just monitors a subprocess and checks if it’s up. This script is named `run-always`

```
set -euf

# monitor a child process
# see if it's up

cpid=
while : ; do
    # if cpid isn't set, spawn child
    if [ -z "$cpid" ]; then
       "$@" &
       cpid="$!"
    fi

    # if child isn't active unset cpid
    if ps -o pid= -p "$cpid"; then
        :
    else
        cpid=
    fi

    sleep 1
done
```

If I use it with a process that exits immediately (like `ls`) then we get the following memory usage when I execute the script with `dash run-always ls`

4476kb and it never grows.

This is the command I’m using to get the memory usage once per second on Linux … there’s probably a way to get the memory and peak memory usage directly from `ps`, but this does the job.

```
 while : ; do cat /proc/"$(ps a | grep run-always | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}')"/status | grep -i 'vmsize\|vmpeak' ; sleep 1; done
```

When I execute the above script with `dash`, the memory usage never grows, it hovers at a constant 4476kb on my machine.

However, when I use bash (`bash run-always ls`), every ten seconds or so it allocates another few kilobytes of memory and never frees it.

Why is bash doing this?

Example output:

```
VmPeak:    16676 kB
VmSize:    16676 kB
VmPeak:    16676 kB
VmSize:    16676 kB
VmPeak:    16676 kB
VmSize:    16676 kB
VmPeak:    16676 kB
VmSize:    16676 kB
VmPeak:    16676 kB
VmSize:    16676 kB
VmPeak:    16676 kB
VmSize:    16676 kB
VmPeak:    16676 kB
VmSize:    16676 kB
VmPeak:    16676 kB
VmSize:    16676 kB
VmPeak:    16676 kB
VmSize:    16676 kB
VmPeak:    16676 kB
VmSize:    16676 kB
VmPeak:    16676 kB
VmSize:    16676 kB
VmPeak:    16680 kB
VmSize:    16680 kB
VmPeak:    16680 kB
VmSize:    16680 kB
VmPeak:    16680 kB
VmSize:    16680 kB
VmPeak:    16680 kB
VmSize:    16680 kB
VmPeak:    16680 kB
VmSize:    16680 kB
VmPeak:    16680 kB
VmSize:    16680 kB
VmPeak:    16680 kB
VmSize:    16680 kB
VmPeak:    16680 kB
VmSize:    16680 kB
VmPeak:    16680 kB
VmSize:    16680 kB
VmPeak:    16684 kB
VmSize:    16684 kB
VmPeak:    16684 kB
VmSize:    16684 kB
VmPeak:    16684 kB
VmSize:    16684 kB
VmPeak:    16684 kB
VmSize:    16684 kB
VmPeak:    16684 kB
VmSize:    16684 kB
VmPeak:    16684 kB
VmSize:    16684 kB
VmPeak:    16684 kB
VmSize:    16684 kB
VmPeak:    16684 kB
VmSize:    16684 kB
VmPeak:    16684 kB
VmSize:    16684 kB
VmPeak:    16684 kB
VmSize:    16684 kB
VmPeak:    16684 kB
VmSize:    16684 kB
VmPeak:    16684 kB
VmSize:    16684 kB
VmPeak:    16684 kB
VmSize:    16684 kB
VmPeak:    16684 kB
VmSize:    16684 kB
VmPeak:    16688 kB
VmSize:    16688 kB
VmPeak:    16688 kB
VmSize:    16688 kB
VmPeak:    16688 kB
VmSize:    16688 kB
VmPeak:    16688 kB
VmSize:    16688 kB
VmPeak:    16688 kB
VmSize:    16688 kB
VmPeak:    16688 kB
VmSize:    16688 kB
VmPeak:    16688 kB
VmSize:    16688 kB
VmPeak:    16688 kB
VmSize:    16688 kB
VmPeak:    16688 kB
VmSize:    16688 kB
VmPeak:    16688 kB
VmSize:    16688 kB
VmPeak:    16692 kB
VmSize:    16692 kB
```

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem, but what you are doing in this script could probably be done better with the `wait` command - or in a case this simple, just not backgrounding the process at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash saves each backgrounded process in a table of active jobs. Because you're spawning new jobs without explicitly checking the old ones, the table potentially increases without bound. The problem goes away if you `disown` the process after backgrounding it or check the exit status using `jobs` before launching the next background process.

For example, this version of your script does not increase in memory usage:

```
set -euf

# monitor a child process
# see if it's up

cpid=
while : ; do
    # if cpid isn't set, spawn child
    if [ -z "$cpid" ]; then
       "$@" &
       disown $!       # Don't waste memory on this red-headed child
       cpid="$!"
    fi

    # if child isn't active unset cpid
    if ps -o pid= -p "$cpid"; then
        :
    else
        cpid=
    fi

    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 2):

As you already discovered that this problem does not appear with dash, it seems to be obvious that there is a high probability that this is caused by a bug.

It does also grow if you are using bash-3.x but very slowly - still faster than with other shells.

I recommend you to make a bug-report against your version of bash.

BTW: I did some tests and there are only two shells where there is no growth at all - regardless how long you wait: `mksh` and the original `Bourne Shell` that was not yet converted to use malloc() instead of sbrk().

All other shells grow very slowly.

Comment: Did you also check the behavior of dash? I ran that script for half an hour and it never allocated more memory.

Comment: Dash is slowly growing like ksh88 and ksh93. I removed the sleep and waited for some minutes.